# Preventing Possible Data Race Conditions

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers, thread-safety

Consider the following code:

```
typedef double (*fpointer)(void*);

typedef struct {
  int data1;
  double data2;
} data_t;

double stuff(void* arg) {
  data_t *d = (data_t *)arg;
  ...
  // Do random things
  ...
  return data2;
}
```

And consider I have a non-blocking function:

```
void func(fpointer f, data_t* d)
```

Which essentially runs `f(d)` but returns immediately without waiting for the `f(d)` to complete (similar to something like MPI_Isend/MPI_Irecv).

Now I want to run `func` hundreds of times, but with different data.  Is something like the code below safe to run without inhibiting a race-condition?  If it does exhibit undefined behaviour, what would be an alternative to achieving such a task without creating hundreds of data structures?

```
data_t d;
d.data1 = 1;
d.data2 = 1.5;

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  d.data2 += 1.0;
  func(stuff, &d);
}
```

If you need more clarification, please let me know.  I appreciate any help.

Comment: Is your code multi-threaded? If so, in what way(s)?

Comment: Technically yes. The multithreading comes from calling `func`.  I'm using qthreads (http://www.cs.sandia.gov/qthreads/) which does task-based parallelism.  `func` is a stand-in for the `qthread_fork(...)` function.

Comment: The definition of *data race* is "two or more simultaneous accesses to the same object at least one of which is a write". If `func` is arranging for another thread to run `stuff(d)`, this is a data race.

Comment: "what would be an alternative to achieving such a task" -- What task? You've given no clue what result you expect. You've got 1000 functions all running asynchronously, all accessing d.data2, which you are all the while modifying ... how could the result possibly be well-defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not safe at all - if, as you imply - there is processing going on in the background.  You're re-using the same instance of `d` for each iteration; `d` is being passed by reference.

Consider making a new copy of `d`, or using pass-by-copy into `func`.  Since `data_t` is relatively small, you won't take much of a hit doing that in this case.

If you can't copy through the parameter, perhaps `func` can copy internally (introduces semantics on `func` you might not want) or your caller can pass in distinct instances.

Comment: Unfortunately I am forced to use the signature of `func`, so I have to pass in a pointer.

Comment: @AlexBrooks You could make a fresh copy of it and pass a pointer to the fresh copy

Comment: @RichardSitze unfortunately I don't have access to modify `func`.  Everything I do has to be done outside of `func` - it's a library function.

Comment: Would doing something like this (in the for loop) work: `d = new data_t(); d.data1 = ...; d.data2 = ...; func(stuff, d);`

Comment: I keep receiving an error: `error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘d = (data_t*)operator new(32u)`. Does this mean I must add a constructor to my struct?

Comment: My C/C++ is a bit rusty - try `new data_t`, not `new data_t()`

Comment: @AlexBrooks `d = new data_t; d->data1 = ...; d->data2 = ...; ... func(stuff, d)`